# Squared Euclidean distance and correlation between two normalized variables: a proportional factor?

Tags: r, correlation, covariance, euclidean-distance

I am using the built-in `iris` dataset, I have already reduced the data to only the numerical columns, and created a scaled dataset:

```
scaled <- scale(iris[1:4])
```

But I am lost when trying to do the following:

*Calculate the Euclidean distances between the columns of `scaled`
using `dist()` function. Show that the squares of these Euclidean distances are proportional to the `(1 - correlation)`s. What is the value of the proportional factor here?*

I tried using `dist()`, but don't think I am getting the correct output:

```
dist(scaled)
```

This prints out a massive output that I am not entirely sure what to do with. I don't know how else to approach this. I don't even know what it means when it asks what is the value of the proportional factor. I am pretty sure that the correlations it wants me to compare it to is

```
cor(scaled)
#             Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#Sepal.Length    1.0000000  -0.1175698    0.8717538   0.8179411
#Sepal.Width    -0.1175698   1.0000000   -0.4284401  -0.3661259
#Petal.Length    0.8717538  -0.4284401    1.0000000   0.9628654
#Petal.Width     0.8179411  -0.3661259    0.9628654   1.0000000
```

But how do I compare the massive output from the `dist()` to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This prints out a massive output that I am not entirely sure what to do with.

You want `dist(t(scaled))` because `dist()` takes distance between rows. Consider your scaled dataset `scaled`. The squared Euclidean distance matrix between columns is:

```
## I have used `c()` outside to coerce it into a plain vector
d <- c(dist(t(scaled)) ^ 2)
# [1] 333.03580  38.21737  54.25354 425.67515 407.10553  11.06610
```

The lower triangular of correlation matrix is (we want lower triangular because the distance matrix is giving lower triangular part):

```
corr <- cor(scaled)[lower.tri(diag(4))]
# [1] -0.1175698  0.8717538  0.8179411 -0.4284401 -0.3661259  0.9628654
```

We then just do what your question asks to compare:

```
d / (1 - corr)
# [1] 298 298 298 298 298 298
```

`iris` dataset has 150 rows, you should realize that `298 = 2 * (150 - 1)`.

---

**Update**

[image: theoretical justification]